# How to translate station codes into HERE API Transit IDs?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

As you'd expect the [HERE Transit API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/what-is.html) uses unique IDs for Travel Operators, Bus Stops, Rail Stations, etc.

As in other countries the UK already has an established system for these IDs in the form of [ATOC](https://wiki.openraildata.com/index.php/TOC_Codes) Codes for Operators, [NaPTAN](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/national-public-transport-access-node-schema) Codes for stops, etc.

Does there exist a way to translate between these two systems, or can anyone help on the best method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the IDs used by HERE Transit API are internal HERE Specific Ids and are not compatible with Ids from other systems.